# Get message queue ID from Key provided

Tags: c, linux, unix, ipc

I have a key for message queue inter process communication, say `key_t = 10`.
I want to get the queue ID if message queue already exist with key value 10.
Currently I am using below code to find the queue is exist or not using return error

```
msgget((key_t)10,IPC_EXCL|IPC_CREAT|0777)
```

but I want to get queue ID and need to close it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `msgget` without using `IPC_EXCL` flag to get existing message queue identifier.

```
mid = msgget((key_t)10, 0);
```

Then, using that identifier you can use remove the message queue by using `msgctl` with `IPC_RMID` flag.

EDIT:

```
key_t ftok(char *pathname, char proj_id);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @sat. How can I generate the unique     'key_t' for my message queue because if some one is using     'key_t=10' then there will be conflict occurs right?

Comment: @BhavithCAcharya, You can use `ftok` to generate a unique `System V IPC key`.

Comment: Thanks @sat. I have other question but it seems like silly please help me out. if I use key_t ftok("tmp/mykey", 'b'); after key is generated I am killing my process so that message queue exist still in my kernel . So I am opening /tmp/mykey using vi /tmp/mykey but key is not visible but it is visible in ipcs -q command

Comment: @BhavithCAcharya, I think you have misunderstood the usage of `ftok`.  `ftok` won't store any `key` into the given filepath. But, It will use those information to generate a unique message queue key. More info read about `ftok` and usage. If you need `key`, you have to store by yourself.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows to accept the answer (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers)

Comment: I already clicked when you response first time but my points are still 6 so it wont be visible to public